Surface flux in a specific direction: why is specific intensity in other directions allowed to contribute?
I'm working with sections 2.3-2.4 in Sara Seager's Exoplanet Atmospheres. The book has these following definitions:

Specific Intensity $I(\vec x, \hat n, \nu, t)$: $dE(\nu, t) = I(\vec x, \hat n, \nu, t)\hat n\cdot \hat k d\Omega dA d\nu dt$
Flux: $\vec{F}(\vec x, \nu, t) = \int_\Omega I(\vec x, \hat n, \nu, t)\hat n d\Omega$
Flux in a specific direction: $F_k(\vec x, \nu, t)=\int_\Omega I(\vec x, \hat n, \nu, t)\hat n\cdot \hat k d\Omega$. The book says that with this $F_k$ 'we are essentially describing the energy flow in one direction'.
My question lies with the last definition. Saying 'flux in a specific direction' is a bit like saying 'mass at a specific point,'. It doesn't make sense to me. Flux is an integration of specific intensity over a solid angle and thus cannot be ascribed to a single 'direction' (just as it's only possible to ascribe a density but not mass value to a point.)
And I don't get the integration either. Say we have an observer looking at a specific surface element $dA$ on a distant planet, and the direction connecting $dA$ with the observer is $\vec k$. Then any beam of radiation with pointing $\hat n \ne \hat k$ would simply miss our observer and should not impact the flux in the observer's direction. Yet the textbook definition $F_k(\vec x, \nu, t)=\int_\Omega I(\vec x, \hat n, \nu, t)\hat n\cdot \hat k d\Omega$ indicates these mispointing beams are also contributing as well, except with a $\hat n\cdot \hat k$ projection factor. Say there's a beam pointing 60$^\circ$ away from the observer, and somehow the observer still get to see half of that energy...???
If you ask me I'd say flux in a specific direction is $F_k(\vec x, \nu, t)=\int_{\Omega Telescope} I(\vec x, \hat n, \nu, t)d\Omega$.

What am I getting wrong at the meaning of $F_k$? The textbook's context is included here for sake of completeness. 

Flux, in terms of power per unit area is in general direction-dependent, unless the radiation is isotropic.
For example, the power emitted by a dipole is zero along its axis and at a maximum for a polar angle of 90 degrees. We can therefore discuss the flux emitted in particular directions.
The second question relates to the definition of specific intensity, which involves emission from a surface element to which ${\bf n}$ is a normal. To express flux per unit area for an arbitrarily oriented area requires us to calculate the projection of that area, which is $dA\  {\bf n}\cdot {\bf k}$.

Thanks for the dipole analogy for the first question! That did make things feel more natural.

For the second question, $\hat n$ here is not the normal to a surface element, but rather a changing vector that's meant to indicate different radiation directions. You can notice in the $F_k(\vec x, \nu, t)$ expression that the integration happens over dΩ, which corresponds to different points of $\hat{n}$.  Also, $\hat k$ is the direction we're interested in. So it's not surface normal $\cdot$ emission direction in this case.

@Splinter_X dA is normal to to n in the definition of specific intensity. That it isn't normal to the surface you define is the reason for the scalar product.
